# Modificar el año de una fecha en Android

Tags: java, android, date

Obtengo una fecha sin año especificado desde un `String` al pasar a objeto `Date` el sistema le asigna año 1970.

Me gustaría cambiar el año pero manteniendo el mes y día de la fecha.

Por ejemplo:

```
fecha de entrada   : --10-08
fecha en ajustada  : 2018-10-08
```

Lo que tengo realizado es el comprobado de fecha y su cast a `Date`, me falta asignar el año.

```
String strDate = "--10-08";

if (strDate.matches("--\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("--MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());

            Date fixDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(fixDate);
            //@Todo modificar el año de la fecha
}
```

Comment: no puedes sustituir el primer `-` por el año actual +1  y luego parsear a Fecha ?

Comment: Falta un poco de claridad en la pregunta. No es claro si quiere sumar 1 al año actual , parece ser eso , por lo que dice en el TODO del código. Tampoco dice si lo quiere funcional independientemente del año.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buenas,

Con esto te debería funcionar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(fixDate);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) +1);
```

Y después obtienes la fecha con un `cal.getTime();`